# How to lock the gain in picamera.campture_sequence command?

Tags: python, pi-4, picamera

I am using `picamera` library in python to capture a sequence of pictures. The `picamera` is connected to a microscope and the microscope moves to different vertical positions and `picamera` capture images at different positions.
There are multiple ways to do so. The first way is to use `picamera`.capture at different positions. The second approach is to use picamera.capture_sequence. I prefer the second approach since it is much faster than the first one.
However there is one caveat to that, recently I started to use a microscope under dark field and bright field. Since the exposure changes dramatically under dark field and bright, the camera is giving me very bad and inconsistent images.

I appreciate any comments on how to lock the exposure time in capture_sequence function in `picamera` so that I can take consistent images under dark field and bright field mode.
Here are some of the things that I've tried.

- I tried to lock the exposure but it was no help. camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
- I tried to lock the camera gain but the gain was changing even though I fixed it.